# sql operator equivalent to !=

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to select all the fields where a certain column is not a value I specify.

I tried this but it didn't work.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE columnname != value
```

### My mistake.

It was another error so I thought it was wrong with `!=` operator cause it was the first time I use it. Sorry guys!

Comment: `!=` is a valid SQL operator. `<>` also works. What exactly do you mean "didn't work". The SQL you posted is valid.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that NULL's are different...

WHERE columnName <> NULL  

will not work as expected, you need to use

WHERE columnName IS NULL  or IS NOT NULL

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE columnname <> value
```

Comment: according to the MySQL spec this is the same as !=

Comment: Yes but by giving an answer of `<>` it appears that his original query of `!=` was wrong, when in fact the issue is something else.

Answer (score 5):

For MySQL:
`!=` or `<>` are correct.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html

You should consider `NULL` columns also.  You can do `WHERE columnname IS NOT NULL` also.

Answer (score 3):

In SQL, I believe inequality is

```
<>
```

though many implementations also allow

```
!=
```

Answer (score 2):

Either `<>` or `!=`

From: [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html) (version 5.0)

> <>, !=
>
> Not equal:
>
> mysql> SELECT '.01' <> '0.01';
>           -> 1 mysql> SELECT .01 <> '0.01';
>           -> 0 mysql> SELECT 'zapp' <> 'zappp';
>           -> 1

Answer (score 1):

You need to post the query you are using, because `!=` works fine for me in MySQL 4.1

As others mentioned, `<>` is equivalent.  The `!=` is ANSI standard (99 I believe).

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE NOT columnname = value
```

Answer (score -1):

NOT IN is one flavor and [here's](http://doc.ddart.net/mssql/sql70/nos-nz.htm) a tsql negate example

Comment: Not applicable, based on the example